# Grails Domains OOP doubts

Tags: oop, grails

This a example of grails that I'm learning,
I have two Domains, and whenever I call the controller, it gives me an error that I gave him a int but needed a package.domain.
User and other is Test. which contain:

Test Domain:

```
Long id
Date created
bool enabled
User user
```

User Domain:

```
Long id
String firstname
String lastname
```

And my controller:

```
user.id = 1
def test = new Test(
    created: new Date(),
    enabled: true,
    user: id));
... test.save(flush:true)
```

I don't know how to get the User domain using their attributes in my Test Domain. Can someone explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Test` constructor expects a domain object for the value for `user` property. So maybe try something like this (replacing `1` as appropriate):

```
def test = new Test(created: new Date(), enabled: true, user: User.get(1));
```

Comment: For a case like this, you should use `User.load(1)` to avoid an unnecessary database lookup. The `User` instance is only there to provide its id as the foreign key, so `load()` is a lightweight approach since it doesn't hit the database unless you access a non-id property.

Comment: What if i wanted to get any atributte, besides the id? Should I use `getByFirstName("john")?`